# "We just need to rename" or "We need just to rename"

Tags: adverb-position, focusing-adverbs

I want to say that just in case we want to rename something (in programming) we should do something. Which of the sentences is correct?

> 1. In case we need just to rename the message...
> 2. In case we just need to rename the message...
> 3. In case we need to just rename the message...

I asked some colleagues but we couldn't agree which is the correct answer for this scenario where I want to emphasize that just in case of renaming we should do something.

Comment: The only one that works for me is 2. 1 and 3 are very awkward. Regarding 3, even if you're in favor of split infinitives, this is not a good place to use one.

Comment: You missed out *"In case we need to rename **just** the message..."* There are at least two more credible positions for ***just*** in your example, including obviously *"**Just** in case we need to rename the message..."*, but you get my point.

Comment: None of your numbered suggestions seem to express what your lead-up suggested (by my reading). In the case of the wording you used in the first sentence (i.e., "just in case"), it almost seems like you're doing something **now** so that **just in case** you need to rename later, you are still able to do so. An example of this emphasis would be: "Just in case we need the file later, we put it in the Recycling Bin instead of really deleting it." Thus, another suggestion might be, "Just in case we need to rename the message later, we leave the 'Editable' checkbox checked."

Comment: You used the correct placement in your opening sentence ("just in case we want to rename something"). Why isn't that in your list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The placement of **just** determines whether your emphasis is on the verb **rename** or on the noun **message**.

a) Renaming is the only thing we need to do
b) The message is the only thing that needs to be renamed.

All three of your examples produce meaning a).

If you wanted meaning b) it would be ".... just the message".

Comment: I wanted to emphasize "rename". Because I wrote on a wiki page where at the beginning it was about something else, and we added new topic (rename) and I wanted to emphasize that it's not about the first topic.

Comment: Then you're grammatically OK with any of the three, though #2 is the one you would hear most from the mouths of native speakers, and #1 is what you would see most often in a printed work that has been copy-edited, but with the word *just* changed to *only*. You could also leave out "message" if your focus is on this new action: "If *renaming* is all we need to do..."

Answer (score 1):

I think any of the options is grammatically correct, but the word *just* is often used rather informally to mean *simply*.

If you intend *just* to be synonymous with *only* it might be better to write:-

"In case we only need to rename the message..."

Answer (score 0):

'Just' here means 'only', and is being applied either to the controlling verb 'need' or to the controlled verb 'rename'.  In this case there is hardly any semantic difference.  Note also that option (3) splits the infinitive, which is fine by me.